# How to remove transparent color ( opacity )

Tags: html, css, transparency, opacity

I have the following Codes:

html...

```
<div id="solidcolor">
    <div class="transcolor">transcolor
        <div class="notranscolor">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css..

```
#solidcolor{
    background: url("http://i45.tinypic.com/o5aycp.gif") repeat; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
}
.transcolor{
    background: blue; 
    opacity: 0.4; 
    height: 100px;
}
.notranscolor{
    background: red; /* I want this color to solid color not transparent color*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Eas/2/)**

**Edit note** I couldn't use rgba() method to set it background-color because I have to set linear gradient color.

**Edit1**

I couldn't get proper solution to this even after applying absolute positioning too. But next idea I would like to do this with calc() method but it doesn't exits. Any idea?

**Edit2**

As @rokburgar has stated an answer, I couldn't able to solve my problem even after applying absolute position. But I wanted to set opacity equal to 1.25 I know this should be 0 to 1 but he has stated 0.4 * 1.0 = 0.4 like this 0.8 * 1.25 = 1 then why does it not work?

Comment: I use JS to hidden the component.

Answer (score 1):

Well since opactiy is inherited, you must separately specify opacity to different elements. One method you could use, is to define only the transparent colored text in a separate `span`, like this:

HTML

```
<div id="solidcolor">
    <div>
        <span class="transcolor">some transparent text</span>
        <div>some normal text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.transcolor {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

---

---

Another method you could use is separate divs like this:

HTML

```
<div id="solidcolor">
    <div>
        <div class="transcolor">some transparent text</div>
        <div>some normal text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.transcolor {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is inherited and cannot be simply removed. One would expect you can reset transparency on a child element.

What you did here means:

```
.notranscolor -> opacity: 0.4 * 1.0 = 0.4
```

Solution:

Absolutly position contents of child div.

[Transparency trick](http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/)